# Floating a div only when certain conditions are met

Tags: css, jsp

I have a .jsp that, based on parameters, can have 1 or 2 tables.  If only one of the parameters is fulfilled I want to have the table centered.  If both parameters are fulfilled I want to float one table left and float the other table right. I can take care of the floating part, I am just unsure on how to have the other condition.  I would think this can be done with some sort of 'if' statement....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll most likely need to use a combination of `<c:choose />` and `<c:if />`.

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${conditionOne && conditionTwo}">
    <table class="tableLeft"></table>
    <table class="tableRight"></table>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <c:if test="${conditionOne || conditionTwo}">
      <table class="tableCenter"></table>
    </c:if>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems to be working pretty well, and a lot cleaner then my 'if' scriptlets... Thanks!